# AWS Amplify AuthException throws error onto the IDE console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

The authentication flow runs as expected with the code below.

The issue I am having is when the user already exists in amplify and then when I redirect the user to sign in I get the below error thrown on to the IDE console.

```
 ERROR | SignUpStateMachine | Emitted error: UsernameExistsException {
I/flutter ( 6521):   "message": "An account with the given phone_number already exists.",
I/flutter ( 6521):   "underlyingException": "UsernameExistsException {\n  message=An account with the given phone_number already exists.,\n}"
```

Is this normal behavior?

```
void _signUpUser() async {
    try {
      Map<CognitoUserAttributeKey, String> userAttributes = {
        CognitoUserAttributeKey.phoneNumber: user.phoneNumber,
      };
      await Amplify.Auth.signUp(
        username: user.phoneNumber,
        password: '$user.phoneNumber',
        options: SignUpOptions(
          userAttributes: userAttributes,
        ),
      ).then(
        (result) {

          var nextStep = result.nextStep.signUpStep.toString();
          if (nextStep == 'AuthSignUpStep.confirmSignUp') {
            user.isSignUp = true;
            switchScreenFn(2);
          }
        },
      );
    } on AuthException catch (e) {
      safePrint('On AuthException Error');
      var exception = e.underlyingException.toString();
      if (exception.contains('UsernameExistsException')) {
        _signInUser();
      }
    }
  }
```